# how to locked excel by cpuid in vba

Tags: excel, vba

**my code is**

```
Public Function notcpuid()

Dim m As String
Const test = "BFEBF55555555"

m = GetCPUID

If m <> test Then
    notcpuid = True
Else
    notcpuid = False
End If

End Function

Function GetCPUID() As String
Dim cimv2, PInfo, PItem ' no idea what to declare these as
Dim PubStrComputer As String
PubStrComputer = "."
Set cimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & PubStrComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set PInfo = cimv2.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Processor")
For Each PItem In PInfo
Next PItem
        GetCPUID = PItem.ProcessorID
    End Function

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If notcpuid Then
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End If

End Sub
```

**Why does it not work?**
**Why does it not work?**
**Why does it not work?**
**Why does it not work?**
**Why does it not work?**
**Why does it not work?**
**Why does it not work?**

**i want excel file protection by vba cpuid.**

Comment: Even if you get this working one can easily bypass it by turning off the macros in their settings or open it in safe mode and remove this code.

Comment: @Scott Craner I put the password on Excel so that they do not have access to the VBA, then I will convert XLSM to exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the items as Object.
You also have your For Each loop out of order.

```
Function GetCPUID() As String

  Dim cimv2 As Object
  Dim PInfo As Object
  Dim PItem As Object 
  Dim PubStrComputer As String

  PubStrComputer = "."
  Set cimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & PubStrComputer & "\root\cimv2")
  Set PInfo = cimv2.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Processor")

  For Each PItem In PInfo
     GetCPUID = PItem.ProcessorID
  Next PItem

End Function
```

BTW, you do know that identical CPUs will return the same ID? Not the same as a serial number. For example:

```
Item                    Value                                                  
------                  -----                                                  
Processor Name          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz                
  Code Name             Kaby Lake                                              
  Info                  Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9                  
  Maker                 GenuineIntel                                           
  ID                    BFEBFBFF000906E9                                       
  Max CPU Speed         3.6 GHz                                                
  Physical CPUs         1                                                      
  Physical Cores        4                                                      
  Logical  Cores        8                                                      
  Address Width         64                                                     
  HyperThreading        Enabled                                                
  VM Firmware           Disabled                                               
  Socket                U3E1
```

Update: Using Powershell I looked at the properties for the CPU_Object. It includes a Serial number but when checked on my PC I got this:

```
PS> $CPU_Object.serialnumber
To Be Filled By O.E.M.
```

HTH