# Protect excel Of the method vba hard drive serial number

Tags: excel, vba

my vba code is

```
Public Function notHDD()

Dim m As String
Const test = "WD-WX22AAAAAA"

m = GetHDD

If m <> test Then
    notHDD = True
Else
    notHDD = False
End If

End Function

Function GetHDD() As String
    Dim Wmi As Object, Disks As Object, Disk As Object
    Set Wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel" & "=impersonate}!root\cimv2")
    Set Disks = Wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive")
    For Each Disk In Disks
    If Len(Disk.SerialNumber) > Len(GetSerialNumber) Then GetSerialNumber = Disk.SerialNumber
    Next
    Set Disk = Nothing
    Set Disks = Nothing
    Set Wmi = Nothing
GetHDD = GetSerialNumber
End Function


Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If notHDD Then
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Why does this code not work?

I want Excel file only on this operating system HDD serial WD-WX22AAAAAA

Close on systems other than this

Comment: Be always more specific about how does your code not working? Syntax error, compile error, compilation ok but wrong answer?

Comment: @Whome I want to locked by vba , HDD serial

Answer (score 0):

Run this script in a DOS prompt `cscript -nologo WMIC_DiskDrive.vbs`. Does it print out disk serial numbers (it should)? Similar code should work in Excel VBA script macros.

```
' Look disks
' cscript -nologo scriptname.vbs
Option Explicit

Dim StdOut: Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut

Dim oWmi: Set oWmi    = GetObject("winMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\Root\CIMv2")
Dim oDisks: Set oDisks= oWmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive")
Dim idx
Dim oItem

for idx=0 to oDisks.count-1
  Set oItem = oDisks.ItemIndex(idx)
  StdOut.writeLine(idx & "=" & oItem.SerialNumber)
next
```

This is Excel VBA test macro, does it print out disk serials? Compare values to your predefined variable. Serial may have a whitespace letters.

```
Public Sub DiskDrives()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim oWmi As Object
    Dim oDisks As Object
    Dim oItem As Object
    Dim idx As Long
    
    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    
    Set oWmi = GetObject("winMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\Root\CIMv2")
    Set oDisks = oWmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive")
    For idx = 0 To oDisks.Count - 1
        Set oItem = oDisks.ItemIndex(idx)
        Debug.Print ("|" & idx & "=" & oItem.SerialNumber & "|")
        ws.Cells(4 + idx, 1).Value = "Disk " & idx
        ws.Cells(4 + idx, 2).Value = "|" & oItem.SerialNumber & "|"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: not work. 

`Function GetHDD() As String
      Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim oWmi As Object
    Dim oDisks As Object
    Dim oItem As Object
    Dim idx As Long`

Comment: `Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    
    Set oWmi = GetObject("winMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\Root\CIMv2")
    Set oDisks = oWmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive")
    For idx = 0 To oDisks.Count - 1
        Set oItem = oDisks.ItemIndex(idx)
        Debug.Print ("|" & idx & "=" & oItem.SerialNumber & "|")
        ws.Cells(4 + idx, 1).Value = "Disk " & idx
        ws.Cells(4 + idx, 2).Value = "|" & oItem.SerialNumber & "|"
    Next
GetHDD = GetSerialNumber
End Function`

Comment: Run my example vba macro code(bind it to a button on worksheet) and check for the print out of hdd serial numbers, you get values?

Comment: plz See this page and help me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287594/how-to-locked-excel-by-cpuid-in-vba

Comment: No values if you run my .vbs test script in DOS console? If still no hdd serials then something weird in WMIC libraries.

Comment: yes,you can edit my vba cod and send full vba next im insert vbe

Comment: I believe have given enough answers and example code to study. If still cannot do it you may need a help of the developer. Just run my example DOS vbs script and Excel vba macro without any changes. If you don't see serials, no error messages then nothing we can do, you need to study more.